# Refactor field type everywhere in Java Project IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a field in my java project. I want to change the field's type everywhere in the project.

I have:

```
String car
```

I want to change it everywhere to

```
Vehicle car
```

A simple replace will not work because apart from changing where it used, I also want to change the return type of functions where it is being returned.

For example-

```js
public String returnCar{
  ......
}
```

I want to change this to

```js
public Car returnCar{
  ...
}
```

I there a way of refactoring like this in IntelliJ?

Thanks

Comment: Not automatically. Best you can do is to try and build a replace regex. Even so it may not be complete. Reason being there is noway for the IDE to tel the difference of say `String returnCar()` and `String returnVehicle()` methods, the method names are for the developer to chose. In the example given if both methods should be of type `Car` the IDE have no way to know.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid doing it manually since there are more than 100 changes. But I think that is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [Type migration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/type-migration.html) in IntelliJ IDEA.

From the docs:
"The Type Migration refactoring lets you automatically change a member type (such as from integer to string), and data flow dependent type entries (such as method return types, local variables, parameters, and so on) across the entire project.

It also lets you automatically convert variable or method return type between arrays and collections. If any conflicts are found IntelliJ IDEA displays the appropriate message."